# Algoritmo de Portugol SE

Tags: portugol, porcentagem

Tenho uma pequena dúvida sobre portugol. A questão pede esses detalhes:

*Acima de R$ 400,00

30% do saldo médio
R$ 400,00 (inclusive) até R$ 300,00

25% do saldo médio
R$ 300,00 (inclusive) até R$ 200,00

20% do saldo médio
Até R$ 200,00

10% do saldo médio.*

Meu código ficou assim:

```
funcao inicio()
{
    real saldo,credito
    escreva("Digite seu saldo médio: ")
    leia(saldo)
    se(saldo>400){credito=0.30 escreva("Seu saldo é de: R$",saldo,"\nSeu bonus é de: R$",(saldo*credito),"\nValor total: R$",(saldo*credito+saldo))}
    se(saldo=400 e saldo=>300){credito=0.25 escreva("Seu saldo é de: R$",saldo,"\nSeu bonus é de: R$",(saldo*credito),"\nValor total: R$",(saldo*credito+saldo))}
    se(saldo=300 e saldo=>200){credito=0.20 escreva("Seu saldo é de: R$",saldo,"\nSeu bonus é de: R$",(saldo*credito),"\nValor total: R$",(saldo*credito+saldo))}
    se(saldo=200){credito=0.10 escreva("Seu saldo é de: R$",saldo,"\nSeu bonus é de: R$",(saldo*credito),"\nValor total: R$",(saldo*credito+saldo))}
}
```

Sempre que tento rodar o programa ele diz que a expressão não foi iniciada corretamente, alguma sugestão sobre? Obrigado pela atenção desde já.

Comment: Troque: `se(saldo=400 e saldo=>300){` por `se(saldo<=400 e saldo=>300){`. Idem demais `se` onde escreveu apenas `=`. O uso da cláusula `senão` nos comandos `se` poderia facilitar seus testes.

Comment: Tentei sua dica mas continuo na mesma, o programa diz que o erro está na linha `se(saldo<=400 e saldo=>300){` tentarei falar com meu professor pra buscar como eu supostamente deveria fazer. Obrigado de coração pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso pode estar acontecendo pois você só colocou um `=`, tente colocar `==`. Quando você coloca `==` você esta vendo **se x é igual a y** e quando você utiliza `=` você esta **declarando uma variavel**. Percebi também que o `>=` esta invertido.

---

Tente mudar isso nas ultimas 4 linhas:

```
se(saldo>400){credito=0.30 escreva("Seu saldo é de: R$",saldo,"\nSeu bonus é de: R$",(saldo*credito),"\nValor total: R$",(saldo*credito+saldo))}
se(saldo==400 e saldo>=300){credito=0.25 escreva("Seu saldo é de: R$",saldo,"\nSeu bonus é de: R$",(saldo*credito),"\nValor total: R$",(saldo*credito+saldo))}
se(saldo==300 e saldo>=200){credito=0.20 escreva("Seu saldo é de: R$",saldo,"\nSeu bonus é de: R$",(saldo*credito),"\nValor total: R$",(saldo*credito+saldo))}
se(saldo==200){credito=0.10 escreva("Seu saldo é de: R$",saldo,"\nSeu bonus é de: R$",(saldo*credito),"\nValor total: R$",(saldo*credito+saldo))}
```